# MongoDB - How can I use a field's value in the first argument of $centerSphere

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to get a negative match for $geoWithin, will be used in mongodb Charts.
all of the required information is in the result of the latest stage in an aggregation i'm constructing in mongodb compass,  the result of that stage looks like this:

```
{
    "PizzaId": "123",
    "info": {
        "timestamp": {
            "$date": "2021-02-15T05:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [33.21883773803711, 33.802675247192383]
        },
        "dayOfWeek": 2,
    },
    "PizzaLocation": [{
        "_id": "456",
        "location": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [37.83396911621094, 37.07674026489258]
        }
    }]
}
```

I want to add a stage after that a filter that checks that info.location is not in a 100 km radius within Pizzalocation.0.location:

```
{
    $match: {
        "info.location.coordinates": {
            $not:
                {
                    $geoWithin: {
                        $centerSphere: [
                            "$PizzaLocation.0.location.coordinates",
                            100 / 6378.1
                        ]
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error: **Point must be an array or object**

Things I tried:

- playing with the field name in centerSphere: removing the 0, or $, using:
  `{$arrayElemAt: ["$PizzaLocation.location.coordinates",0]}` 
  even used the [lon,lat] format and put

```
[{$arrayElemAt: [{$arrayElemAt: ["$PizzaLocation.location.coordinates",0]},0]},  
{$arrayElemAt: [{$arrayElemAt: ["$PizzaLocation.location.coordinates",0]},1]}]
```

- setting literal coordinates instead of field name, it worked, but I need to use a field.
- creating a view that will hold the centerSphere itself, and use a lookup to get it, but mongoDB didn't recognize $geoWithin nor $centerSphere in $addField aggregation

Things I verified:

- I used $project stage on  `{$arrayElemAt: ["$PizzaLocation.location.coordinates",0]}` , and indeed it showed in the array: [lon,lat]
- I used $project stage on

```
{$arrayElemAt: [{$arrayElemAt: ["$PizzaLocation.location.coordinates",0]},0]}
```

and

```
{$arrayElemAt: [{$arrayElemAt: ["$PizzaLocation.location.coordinates",0]},1]}
```

and indeed it showed a number for each one.

So, how can I use a field's value(s) in the first argument of $centerSphere.
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can't do it, let's first understand why not.

From the [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) docs:

> The query syntax is identical to the read operation query syntax;

This means `$match` queries use the same syntax as `find` queries. and unsurprisingly [$geoWithin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/) is a query operator.
Unfortunately query syntax can not access the document values as part of the query. This is also the reason why your query fails, the "coordinates" you pass are being parsed as a string expression.

For example this following query:

```
{
  $match: {
    field1: {$eq: "$field2"}
  }
}
```

Matches: `{ field1: "$field2"}` but no `{ field1: 1, field2: 1 }`

Again this is just the query language parser's behaviour so there's not much you can do.

The alternative is to use an the [$geoNear](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) stage, but not only there is no easy way to combine it with `$not` logic there are additional restrictions like it having to be the first stage of the pipeline and so on.

The best I can recommend is split your query into 2 parts, 1 fetch the document you need and only then re-query it using `$geoWithin` with the proper coordinates input.